# How to get data from udp tracker?

Tags: php, udp, protocols, tracker

I appeal to the tracker as follows:

`http://tracker3.torrentino.com/scrape?info_hash=X%F7%0D%D1%ED0%FE%CF%D15%AF%F8%81%C3t-%D7%94%BB%9F`

And get in return:

```
d5:filesd20:X÷
Ñí0þÏÑ5¯øÃt-×”»Ÿd8:completei22e10:downloadedi121e10:incompletei4eee5:flagsd20:min_request_intervali1800eee
```

I also know that they can get through file_get_contents

But how to get data from UDP tracker? How to access it?

Comment: I would assume that's via a socket, [`stream_socket_client`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.stream-socket-client.php) supports opening UDP connections.

Comment: hakre, I understand that bad, could you help me make a script? Please.

Comment: There perhaps is a good reason this is hard to understand for you?

Comment: I understand what you are good at this, but the first time I work with sockets, and have no idea how to work with them.

Comment: Well, then you need to learn a bit. Next to that you also need to learn about the udp tracker protocol. PHP code for a server is available here: https://github.com/Devristo/udp-torrent-tracker